# How to display Hateoas _link for multiple relationships between models?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, relationship, hateoas, hal

I currently have a REST + HATEOAS + HAL API using `_links` for the client to navigate the api.

I have a few models.

```
#User 
   Long id
   String username
   @Many to Many
   List<Trip> trips
   etc.

#Trip
   Long id
   String title
   etc.
   @Many to Many
   List<User> users
   @OneToMany
   List<Place> places

#Place
   Long id
   String title
   @Many to One
   Trip trip
   @OneToOne  <---- user doesn't know about relationship
   User user 
   @OneToMany
   List<Vote> votes

#Vote
   Long id
   boolean vote
   @Many to One
   Place place
   @OneToOne  <---- user doesn't know about relationship
   User user
```

**The problem I am facing is format for the urls**

example: `api/users/1`
returns:

```
 {
  ...userInfo
 "_links": [{
     "self":{
       "href": "api/users/1",
       "method": "GET"
     }
     "trips": [{
       "href": api/users/1/trips.
       "method": "GET"
     },
     { 
       "href": "api/users/1/trips",
       "method": "POST"
     }]
 }
```

With an individual place however

Would the url be: `api/users/1/trips/1/places/3`

Making a individual vote: `api/users/1/trips/1/places/3/votes/2`

Or with url's do you begin simplifying the deeper you go?

example for and individual place: `trips/1/places/3`

making vote be: `places/3/votes/2`

I have looked at a-lot of examples but most usually stop at a single relationship between two entities.